# How do you save the license key for Method R Workbench on Linux 6?

Tags: linux, database, oracle, performance

I navigate to Help -> License, then click the checkbox that allows me to edit the key. However, I don't see a way to save the entry. When I close and reopen the License window, the key has not been saved.

Profiler Version - 7.0.2.3

Workbench (Tools) Version - 4.1.1.2

Oracle Linux 6 with the gnome-classic desktop.

Output from 'uname -a':
Linux localhost.localdomain 4.1.12-94.3.6.el7uek.x86_64 #2 SMP Tue May 30 19:25:15 PDT 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Output from 'cat /etc/redhat-release':
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.3 (Maipo)

Comment: Can you please include the output of `uname -a` and `cat /etc/redhat-release`?

Comment: Additionally, since this is an Oracle added-value product, please add the oracle tag to your question. Welcome to SO.

Comment: Thanks, Jeff. I've added the requested details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems. First, our Linux product requires the 32-bit C libraries. You can install them like this:

```
sudo yum install glibc.i686
```

Second, in gnome-classic, window controls don't display for some of our dialogs. You can close those dialogs with ESC. Or, for gnome and gnome-classic, you can right-click and see a context menu presented by the window manager. That context menu will include a close option.